# windows server multiple user session active possible?

Tags: windows, windows-10

My question on superuser https://superuser.com/posts/1235951

Does windows server allow "multiple users" to be active at the same time?
I am not talking about concurrent remote connections. I want multiple users to be active and computing my stuff. I use users as kind of sandboxing right now.

I could run multiple windows 10 machines right now, but I don't need all resources of a machine. So I'd like to run multiple "instances" of windows if you so will. Windows users are a good example of what will work for me. If only my application would run as every user would be "logged in" right.

I have no experience with windows-servers so I do not now how it differs from the casual windows software at all.

Thanks!

Comment: Your link isn't working. But, if it is the post I think it is, the limitation is with the software not the OS. But, your question, as it is currently asked is so vague that it is impossible to answer because it is apparent you aren't asking the right question.  Every modern version of Windows allows multiple users to be logged on. Unless you are able to clarify, in detail, what you are doing and with what software you will not receive any help.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Windows client operating system does not support multiple interactive login at the same time, Terminal Server do.

The console session can't be splitted, it's a 1x1 relationship, terminal server or client operating system.